# asp:FileUpload control, selecting a file means page no longer resolves when upload button clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="UploadVideo.ascx.cs"      Inherits="Controls_UploadVideo" %>

<h4>Select a video file to upload:</h4>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>

    <asp:FileUpload id="fuUploadVideo"                  
        runat="server">
    </asp:FileUpload>
    <br /><br />

    <asp:Button id="btnUploadVideo" 
        Text="Upload file"
        OnClick="btnUploadVideo_Click"
        runat="server">
    </asp:Button>      

    <hr />

    <asp:Label id="UploadStatusLabel"
        runat="server">
    </asp:Label>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnUploadVideo" />
</Triggers>
```

If use the file upload control to select a video file then clicking the file upload button does not resolve a webpage. Everything is being run on my local machine.

If no file is selected then it goes to the website I expect. Does anyone know why this might be the case?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? What do you mean by 'run on my local machine'. Can you add your code-behind, especially the btnUploadVideo_Click method (but also any other relevant bits).

Comment: file upload cannot work in update panel remove update panel and try it's works

Comment: I am running the website using the Visual Studio debugger. I would post the code behind but break points are telling me I never actually make it back to the code behind code.

Comment: After removing the update panel. The behavior did not change. So I decided to try uploading smaller files. Doing this changed the behavior. It appears that 44.1 MB files are too big for the update control to handle in the time I am giving them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I'm aware, standard `FileUpload` doesn't work inside an UpdatePanel. You could use [AsyncFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx) control instead.

Comment: Getting rid of the UpdatePanel had no effect.

Comment: I decided to try another test. I had been picking large video files. So I created an empty text file and selected it. This got me back to the server. Next I tried a text file with some content and I returned to the server as well.

It appears that this has something to do with the videofiles being so large.

Comment: @Jeremy: you could play with `<httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />` but in any case the standard file upload is not very appropiate for large files (basically there is no feedback to user, there are other better options)

Comment: At this point I am thinking that I should scrap the upload entirely as it is meant to make it faster for me to put new videos on the site.

I am thinking that I will change it to let me post a URL and upload the videos through FTP.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [lenghty post](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2008/04/01/file-upload-in-updatepanel-asp.net-ajax.aspx) about this and indeed a `FileUpload` doesn't work inside an `UpdatePanel`. There are workarounds, and Claudio's solution will probably be the most easy for your situation.